# Filter rows of multiindex columns in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataframe. When I tried to select rows with `data[('PIC_next','last')] == 'Business'`, all rows return `False`.

Is it the right way to filter multiindex column?

I have referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581517/filtering-rows-with-multiindex-columns). It seems that I am correct.

I created this dataframe by using `groupby`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are correct.

Reason why not match should be in data, maybe traling whitespaces.

You can check it:

```
print (data[('PIC_next','last')].tolist())
```

And then remove it:

```
data[('PIC_next','last')].str.strip() == 'Business'
```